# Can I use a band saw to make a cutting board?

Tags: band-saw

I don't really want a table saw because I think I could use the bandsaw/band saw for more things like resawing and curves.  Is it feasible to use a bandsaw for a cutting board (and kind, on grain, strips, or just a cutout single piece of Maple)?  Looking at the big box kind or a used 9" or 10" band-saw.

Comment: Bandsaw should be able to do a fine job for this task.

Comment: You can certainly use a bandsaw for this, but just to mention you can do the basic cutting that many cutting boards require quite feasibly just using one or more hand saws. On power saws generally though, a bandsaw is in the opinion of many much preferable to a table saw if you're going to have just one in the shop. They're of course far more versatile as well as being significantly safer to use.

Comment: Did you mean "any kind"?

Comment: Is it true the bandsaw is the tool of choice most in the UK where the table saw is what most use in the US?

Comment: @johnny, hard to say really. Many do have bandsaws only, but given how common table saws *seem* to be in America that's surprisingly also true enough of small shops in the US. I think fundamentally it can sometimes break down to how much work the person does with sheet goods, which the table saw excels at working with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done that: duplicate an old pig-shaped board with a fresh scrap of hardwood.  Trace the outline, cut out with a bandsaw, finish up the curves with files, and then use a router table to round over the top.

A bandsaw would *not* be good for making strips to glue up into a butcherblock style piece. It's not precise and straignt enough; though if you follow up on the jointer you can make it work, albeit with a lot more waste and possibly non-parallel sides to the strip.

If you make a *real* butcher-block, where the strips are turned sideways so the end-grain is the cutting surface, then the board's original top/bottom are the edges to glue up, and the cut sides are the new face. A jointer won't work on the endgrain, and the bandsaw is probably great for cutting slices from a large chunk of maple: it's what I would have used if I had one. The table saw blade was not tall enough to go through so I had to flip the piece and cut from both faces, and this produced a less-than-smooth cut that took more work (and more waste) to clean up.

So, it depends on what you're doing. It could be a second choice or a primary choice, depending on the nature of the cutting board you're making.

Answer (score 8):

A Bandsaw will certainly cut the wood, but the edges will require additional work since the cut will have more surface striations and the overall surface would be less flat where the table saw cut will be much smoother and flatter. I recommend  using a hand plane or planner to prepare the surfaces for gluing.

Comment: What does surface striations mean?

Comment: It's the ridges and curves you get when you cut something with the band saw. To remove that you would definitely plane the cut surfaces somehow before gluing.

Answer (score 4):

A bandsaw would be more that adequate for this job. In fact it would almost be required it you intended to make a cutting board that was shaped different than a standard rectangle. However it likely won't be the only tool you use.

In this [video by Scott Lewis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lR9_CjQYZj4) you can see him cutting the stock that is to be laminated with the bandsaw (This happens around 39 seconds into the video). The video appears to show all tools that were used. He is pretty good about using cabinet scapers, custom sanding blocks and regular sandpaper. You *could* conclude that he only used a jointer and a bandsaw for the main cutting board.

Lamination can be a rather involved subject but lamination succeeds best when the faces being glued are perfectly mated to each other i.e smooth. You need to get a high tooth count blade in order to get near finish ready.

I would still take a pass with a scraper just in case. When cutting wood with tools like table saws and band saws etc. you should never expect to get a finish ready cut.

If you actually watched the video you will really see the bandsaw in action is it is used to create intricate details into the board. So not only is the bandsaw a valid tool for this job it can do some amazing things.

Answer (score 0):

A bandsaw will work but you have to consider the blades. They will full faster and the size makes a big difference so you will be changing then all the time. They dull faster you will be buying more and it's hard to get perfect cuts. You can do most things with the tablesaw that a bandsaw can do like cutting chives and relaxing on a tablesaw as well but it won't be as easy as it is on a bandsaw. Bandsaw are cheap used I would get that first and then you'll see and want a tablesaw as well.

Comment: "Full faster"?  "Then"=>"them".

Comment: I am assuming you are referring to the gullets on the blade. This all depends on which blade you are using and how fast you are moving the wood. If you know what blades you are using and are aware of proper maintenance for the tool you should be ok. Blades can and will still fail of course no matter what.